# Taking screenshots in XFCE 4 (Debian 9.12 Stretch)

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xfce, screenshot

What is the keyboard shortcut for taking a simple screenshot in Debian 9.12 Stretch with XFCE 4? I have tried different hotkey combinations suggested online, but none works:

> PrntScrn
>
> Ctrl + PrntScrn
>
> Alt + PrntScrn
>
> Shift + PrntScrn
>
> Ctrl + Shift + PrntScrn
>
> Ctrl + Alt + PrntScrn
>
> etc.

Comment: It's usually PrintScreen for most desktop environments.

Comment: @mosvy: Please kindly read the question before downvoting or salty commenting. As I wrote, I tried all obvious keyboard shortcuts. HardInfo gives XFCE 4 as the desktop environment.

Comment: @DKBose: Yes it is.

Comment: @david Do you have the utility `xfce4-screenshooter`?

Comment: I have this one: https://imgur.com/7lRwpOE, https://imgur.com/WYBhOvm. Problem is that hotkeys don't work

Comment: @mosvy: Yes, edit history is public. Please read the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will be referencing [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306689/making-a-screenshot-in-xfce) about how to create a keyboard shortcut for the purpose of creating screenshots using the XFCE desktop environment.

> Go to:
>
> > XFCE Menu > Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts
>
> and add the `xfce4-screenshooter -f` command to use the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key in order to take fullscreen screenshots.

Looking at the `xfce-screenshooter` [documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/screenshooter/usage), you can see all the different options for taking screenshots.

> The -w option
>
> - The -w option allows you to take a screenshot of the active window.
>
> The -f option
>
> - The -f option allows you to take a screenshot of the entire screen.
>
> The -r option
>
> - The -r option allows you to select a region to be captured by clicking and dragging a rectangle over the area of screen that you wish to capture, before releasing the mouse button.
>
> The -d option
>
> - The -d option followed by a positive integer allows you to set the delay before taking the screenshot when the -w, the -f or the -r option is given.
>
> The -s option
>
> - The -s option followed by the path to an existing folder allows you to set where the screenshots are saved. This option only has an effect if the -w, the -f or the -r option is given.
>
> The -o option
>
> - If the -o option is given, followed by an application name, the screenshot will be saved to the system's temporary directory and opened with the application whose name is to be given after -o. This option only has an effect if the -w, the -f or the -r option is given.
>
> The -u option
>
> - If the -u option is given, the screenshot will be hosted on Imgur. See above for more details. This option only has an effect if the -w, the -f or the -r option is given.

There are a lot of different options available to you that you can quickly default to. You can also just have the hotkey of your choice launch `xfce-screenshooter` with no options to open up the application and allow you to choose between them in a graphical manner.

I will also include a link to the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ScreenShots) on how to create a screenshot.

### In Conclusion

Using the Keyboard > Application Shortcuts menu will allow you verify what your keyboard shortcuts are and allow you to add, remove, and edit them.

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Comment: how can i map xfce4-screenshooter -r using the command line? my hands are glued to the keyboard and i'm allergic to rodents XP